# Error al guardar datos en vector en Java

Tags: java, array

estoy comenzando con objetos en java y en este programa que tengo que ingresar salario y legajos de trabajadores e imprimir cuanto seria el monto total a pagar en salario cada mes, el problema comienza al guardar datos en vectores, NetBeans me tira:

> ```
> Exception in thread main java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 
> at pruebas.Pruebas.<init>(Pruebas.java:22) at 
> pruebas.PruebasMain.main(PruebasMain.java:12)
> ```

```
package pruebas;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebasMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int trabajador;

        System.out.print("Ingrese cantidad de trabajadores: ");
        trabajador = in.nextInt();

        Pruebas datos = new Pruebas(trabajador);

        datos.Imprimir();

    }
}
```

Clase Pruebas

```
package pruebas;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pruebas {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int legajo;
    private int salario;
    private int totalmes;
    private int trabajador;
    private int vectorsalario[] = new int[trabajador];
    private int vectorlegajo[] = new int[trabajador];

    public Pruebas(int trabajador) {
        this.trabajador = trabajador;

        for (int i = 0; i < trabajador; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese legajo del trabajador: ");
            legajo = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese salario del trabajador: ");
            salario = in.nextInt();

            vectorsalario[i] = salario;
            vectorlegajo[i] = legajo;
        }

    }

    public void CalculoMes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorsalario.length; i++) {
            totalmes = totalmes + vectorsalario[i];
        }
    }

    public void Imprimir() {
        CalculoMes();
        System.out.print("El total a pagar del mes es: " + totalmes);

    }
}
```

Comment: Aunque la pregunta está perfectamente planteada y aportas lo necesario para responderla, te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida y ganarte una medalla extra por ello. Así conocerás algunos detalles extras del sitio. Bienvenido/a!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fallo está en que no conoces *aún* el ciclo de vida de los objetos en Java (todos hemos pasado por esto):

Cuando llamas al constructor con `new Pruebas(5);` (por ejemplo) pasa lo siguiente:

1. La máquina virtual (VM) crea una instancia nueva de la clase Pruebas, inicializando todos sus valores a su valor por defecto:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //crea una instancia de Scanner
    private int legajo; //un int sin valor explícito -> se inicializa a 0
    private int salario; //un int sin valor explícito -> se inicializa a 0
    private int totalmes; //un int sin valor explícito -> se inicializa a 0
    private int trabajador; //un int sin valor explícito -> se inicializa a 0
    
    //trabajador vale 0, array de 0 elementos
    private int vectorsalario[] = new int[trabajador]; 
    //trabajador vale 0, array de 0 elementos
    private int vectorlegajo[] = new int[trabajador];
```

2. Una vez creada la instancia en memoria, se llama automáticamente al constructor:

```
    public Pruebas(int trabajador) {
        this.trabajador = trabajador; //trabajador valdrá 5

        for (int i = 0; i < trabajador; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese legajo del trabajador: ");
            legajo = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese salario del trabajador: ");
            salario = in.nextInt();

            //los vectores no se han re-inicializado, su tamaño es cero.
            //al intentar acceder a la primera posición, que no existe,
            //se produce la excepción
            vectorsalario[i] = salario;
            vectorlegajo[i] = legajo;
        }

    }
```

La solución es inicializar todo en el constructor:

```
public class Pruebas {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int legajo;
    private int salario;
    private int totalmes;
    private int trabajador;
    private int[] vectorSalario;
    private int[] vectorLegajo;

    public Pruebas(int trabajador) {
        this.trabajador = trabajador;
        this.vectorsalario = new int[trabajador];
        this.vectorLegajo = new int[trabajador];

        for (int i = 0; i < trabajador; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese legajo del trabajador: ");
            legajo = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese salario del trabajador: ");
            salario = in.nextInt();

            vectorsalario[i] = salario;
            vectorlegajo[i] = legajo;
        }

    }

    // ... resto de código
```